# How to add a column to a database table using Subsonic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, subsonic

I am trying to add a column to a database table in an application that is using `SubSonic 2.0.3.0` as the generator for the database layer.

I just cant get the hang of it. I tried to manually update the generated file of the table but it doesn't work. I have been trying to get the subsonic files regenerated but i cant find the `sonic.exe` tool that's needed? Can anyone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the latest 2.0 version of the project from https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0, after you build it the sonic.exe will be in SubSonic\SubCommander\bin\Debug.

Then I've just got a little script file

```
del /q "DAL\*.*"
"..\..\ExternalResources\lib\sonic.exe" generate /out "DAL"
pause
```

Is that enough to get you on track?